# Concurrent CPLEX processes a lot slower than single process

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing, cplex

I am modelling and solving a linear program (LP) using single-threaded CPLEX with Java (under Linux). My aim is to solve multiple small LPs in parallel threads, ideally with each core independently solving one LP.

The problem is that solving two or more LPs in parallel is a lot slower than solving a single LP. In a very simple test, I concurrently started multiple identical processes that would solve the same LP. The difference in runtimes between starting a single process and starting multiple ones is huge:

- 1 process: 180 s
- 2 processes: 225 s
- 3 processes: 280 s

Likewise, starting multiple threads from the same process to concurrently solve multiple LPs was a lot slower than solving a single LP.

I suspected memory access could be the bottleneck, but testing a piece of code that would often read and write to memory resulted in comparable runtimes:

- 1 process: 87 s
- 2 processes: 85 s
- 3 processes 88 s

Any idea what could be causing the slowness?

The machine I am running this has 6 cores and plenty of memory to avoid any swapping. The IBM ILOG Cplex library is version 12.5.

Comment: I'm seeing faster, not slower. 1 process solved 1 problem in 180s. 2 processes solved 2 in 225s = 112.5s/problem (faster). 3 solved 3 in 280 = 93.3s/problem (faster still, nearly double the speed of one process). Or had you already done that division in the numbers you gave?

Comment: You are right, but seeing how the processes are completely independent, with no synchronization issues to speak of, I would have expected that two/three processes would take roughly the same amount of time as only one process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple threads enabled, CPLEX will use the concurrent optimizer.  That means it runs the dual-simplex in one thread and the barrier algorithm in the remaining other threads.  CPLEX reports the answer of the algorithm that finishes first.  So if you have 6 cores, then it it likely using 1 thread for dual simplex and 5 threads for barrier.  When you try to solve 3 LPs simultaneously, they are stealing cycles from each other.  You can use just the dual simplex (which always uses just 1 thread) by setting the parameter RootAlg to 2.  You could also set the parameter [AuxRootThreads](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r2/index.jsp?topic=/ilog.odms.cplex.help/Content/Optimization/Documentation/CPLEX/_pubskel/CPLEX1053.html) to limit the number of threads used by each LP solve.
  You should check which of the algorithms (Primal, Dual, or Barrier) work better on your problem.  If Barrier, which can take advantage of multiple threads, works the best, you might be better off running each model serially and letting CPLEX do the parallelization.

Comment: I am not using the parallel mode: the barrier algorithm is a lot slower for my problem and I kind of know the parameters that work best: dual with presolve or primal with no presolve

Comment: @DavidNehme Moreover, I understood that he is running the same model with different input parameters simultaneously, not that he is using CPLEX for exploiting parallel solving of the same instance.

Comment: @JeanValjean I understand, he wants to run multiple models with a single thread each and with 6 cores, the 3 parallel solves should run as fast as 1.  The issue is that CPLEX **does** try to take advantage of multiple cores by **default**, so unless you set parameters on each CPLEX instance, you CPLEX will use multiple threads which will compete for resources.

Comment: @DavidNehme Supposing that I understood the problem... However, he can try to change some of cplex parameters. The `parallel mode switch` parameter that I suggested could be useful. Another parameter is related to the number of threads invoked by a CPLEX instance (see [global default thread count](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Filog.odms.cplex.help%2FContent%2FOptimization%2FDocumentation%2FCPLEX%2F_pubskel%2FCPLEX861.html)).

Comment: @DavidNehme Moreover, he can read a consideration about threads and performance [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Filog.odms.cplex.help%2FContent%2FOptimization%2FDocumentation%2FCPLEX%2F_pubskel%2FCPLEX861.html).

Answer (score 0):

First, let me highlight that the comment by [T.J.Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) is right. Generally speaking, the real speed-up could not be linear in a multi-thread approach. In fact, consider that: 1) there are other processes that runs on the machine, not only yours; 2) the CPU architecture is very important, as well as other hardware (mother board, RAM, etc.), then these may affect the performance of your algorithm.

I suggest to play with the several options included in CPLEX, e.g. with [`parallel mode switch`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r2/index.jsp?topic=/ilog.odms.cplex.help/Content/Optimization/Documentation/CPLEX/_pubskel/CPLEX1022.html).

Finally, another important consideration is about your question: you are presuming that your implementation is good, but there is no evidence about that.

Comment: Thanks. Your points are valid but let me remark that I was expecting a vary good scalability of my problem since each optimisation is ran in its own process at OS level and there's thus definitely no synchronization, only scheduling involved. The runtimes are the ones that CPLEX needs to solve the problem, and my assumption is that the library is solidly implemented. The other test I ran did show linear scalability of a memory intensive piece of code by the same approach.

Comment: You are assuming that CPLEX library is implemented in order to be scalable in a multithread system. Who can guarantee this. Moreover, none can help you without a complete view of your code. This is Stackoverflow, the site focuses on computer programming issues. Let me say that there is no computer programming issue here. I can see how you create the cplex instance, how you submit your models, etc. Hence, all the answers will be theoretic. No practical answer can be provided! Sorry

Comment: Yes I was actually assuming that, and apparently I was overoptimistic. I did not include any code because my problem is behavioural rather than related to one obvious piece of code. It is therefore theoretical answers that I was expecting. You help is very much appreciated, though.

Comment: @elcomandantetibi I'd would glad to help in solving a programming issue related to CPLEX.